# How to expires the ember-simple-auth session?

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I am using ember-simple-auth for authentication in my application. I have created my custom Authenticator. Upon successful authentication, the server returns the token and expire time which I store in session storage of simple-auth.

My question is how do I expires or invalidate this session based on the expire time set in the session?

I also need to invalidate the session on browser close event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the session's [`invalidate` method](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Session-invalidate). To call that after the expiration time that your server returns you could setup a timer with [`Ember.run.later`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later) or use automatic token refreshing as defined in the OAuth 2.0 standard which [Ember Simple Auth OAuth 2.0 supports out of the box](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-oauth2#the-authenticator).