# Invalidate session with custom authenticator

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Using ember-cli 0.1.2 and ember-cli-simple-auth 0.7.0, I need to invalidate the session both on client and server. As explained [here](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Authenticators-Base) I need to do something similar to the `authenticate` method making an ajax request to the server and ensuring its success before emptying the session:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from "simple-auth/authenticators/base";

var CustomAuthenticator = Base.extend({
  tokenEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/auth/login',

  restore: function(data) {

  },

  authenticate: function(credentials) {
    var _this = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url:         _this.tokenEndpoint,
        type:        'POST',
        data:        JSON.stringify({ email: credentials.identification, password: credentials.password }),
        contentType: 'application/json'
      }).then(function(response) {
        Ember.run(function() {
          resolve({ token: response.token });
        });
      }, function(xhr, status, error) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        Ember.run(function() {
          reject(response.error);
        });
      });
    });
  },

  invalidate: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.ajax({ 
        url: _this.tokenEndpoint, 
        type: 'DELETE' 
      }).then(function(response) {
        resolve();
      }, function(xhr, status, error) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        Ember.run(function() {
          reject(response.error);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  // invalidate: function() {
  //   var _this = this;
  //   return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
  //     Ember.$.ajax({ url: _this.tokenEndpoint, type: 'DELETE' }).always(function() {
  //       resolve();
  //     });
  //   });
  // }
});

export default {
  name : 'authentication',
  before : 'simple-auth',
  initialize : function(container) {
    container.register('authenticator:custom', CustomAuthenticator);
  }
};
```

My logout API endpoint need the token (in the headers). How do I pass it? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788580/how-to-expires-the-ember-simple-auth-session) but my authorizer seems ignoring it and I got a 401:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';

var CustomAuthorizer = Base.extend({
  authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions){
    Ember.debug("AUTHORIZING!");
  }
});

export default {
  name : 'authorization',
  before : 'simple-auth',
  initialize : function(container) {
    container.register('authorizer:custom', CustomAuthorizer);
  }
};
```

My `environment.js`:

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'wishhhh',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  // TODO: disabled because of https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2174
  ENV.contentSecurityPolicyHeader = 'Disabled-Content-Security-Policy'

  ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:custom',
    // crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://localhost:3000']
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['*']
  }

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'auto';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

The following is the Ember inspector output when, eventually, I try to logout:
[image]

Comment: BTW: you need to install the authenticator's `restore` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to marcoow, I found out that it was actually a problem with every request not only the logout one. My authorizer never got called. Problem was environment setup of `crossOriginWhitelist` which, in order to work with my dev API, I had to set to `['http://127.0.0.1:3000']`. Neither `['http://localhost:3000']` nor `[*]` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually configure Ember Simple Auth to use your custom authorizer? In that case it should authorize the session invalidation request automatically.

Alternatively you could add the token in the authenticator's invalidate method which gets passed the session's contents.

Comment: hi marco. I edited my question with `environment.js`. Maybe the problem have something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716668/simple-auth-addon-seems-to-not-be-reading-env-config). But I couldn't try because I don't know where I should exactly put that snippet

Comment: You don't need `window.ENV` anymore. Is `Ember.debug("AUTHORIZING!");` actually executed ever (of course you'd need to actually add the header in that method of course)?

Comment: No it's not executed. I noticed from the Ember Inspector that an actual authorizer container named custom exists and among its properties `authenticator: authenticator:custom` is maybe wrong.. have a look to the attached screenshot...

Comment: what you're seeing is the `authorizer:custom` with it's season property that has an `authenticator` property. Are any other requests authorized by the authorizer?

Comment: resolved by attempts... It was CORS related problem. I had to use `crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000']` for `ENV['simple-auth']`. Previous attempts with `['*']` and `['http://localhost:3000']` did not worked. Thanks a lot marco even to guide me to the right track